# GCP authorized view on BQ external table still requires bucket access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, view, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have data in a GCS bucket and an external BQ table created in dataset *A* to query this data.

I would like to provide access to a user, *Alice*, just to a small part of the data, not the whole. I want to use [Authorized view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views) for that.

I created a view with limiting conditions in a new dataset *B*, and authorized this view for dataset *A*. I verified that I can see in the Console the created view is authorized for dataset *A*. Then, I provided read access to dataset *B* for *Alice*.

When I asked *Alice* to query the view, she got a permission error:

> Access Denied: BigQuery: Permission denied while globbing file pattern. *Alice* does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist). Please make sure gs://bucket-path/*.parquet.gz is accessible via appropriate IAM roles, e.g., Storage Object Viewer or Storage Object Creator.

Are my expectations wrong?

Why does *Alice* need access to the whole underlying bucket when the whole point of authorized views is to be able to provide just limited access to the data?

Comment: Authorized views grant permission to a view to access to a table or to another views. Sadly authorized views does not work with External tables (Cloud Storage, Drive, Google Sheet,...) I heard something was on track, but not for now.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks. That would explain this behavior. Don't you have some link to official docs or some ticket where this is mentioned or discussed, please?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere If you post your comment as an answer and add a link to the source, I would happily mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find any official documentation. I stated that because of my experience, but nothing documented, and can change at any time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with Google Support and as of now (2023-10), **authorized views do not work with BigQuery external tables** on GCS buckets.

The recommended approach would be to use [Biglake external tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/biglake-intro), which should work with authorized views.